# Setting WPF datagrid selected row color at application level

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

My datagrid row selection color by default is dark blue, when I change my windows 7 theme to windows classic theme it looks too dark and ugly.

I want to set the row selection color of all the datagrids in my wpf application to something else which looks better on both windows 7 and classic. (also if you know what color is good on both)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the Background for a selected `DataGridRow`/`DataGridCell` at application level you can add the following Style to App.xaml

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

As for which color to use, I don't have any really good tips besides trying a few until you find one that you like :)